# Props not displaying from fetch call

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to display recipes and not sure if I have this setup correctly. I am pulling recipes from a rails api via get fetch request. At the moment nothing is displaying.

Here is my recipe container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import RecipeList from '../components/RecipeList'
import RecipeInput from '../components/RecipeInput'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { postRecipes } from '../actions/postRecipes.js'
import { getRecipes } from '../actions/getRecipes'


class RecipeContainer extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        getRecipes()
      }
    

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
               <RecipeInput postRecipes={this.props.postRecipes} /> 
               <RecipeList getRecipes={this.props.recipes} />
            </div>
        )
    }

    

}

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
   recipes: state.recipes
})


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return{
    postRecipes: (recipe) => dispatch(postRecipes(recipe)),
    getRecipes: () => dispatch(getRecipes())
    // deleteRecipe: id => dispatch({type: 'Delete_Recipe', id})
    }
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(RecipeContainer)
```

Here is my get request....notice that I am returning my Recipe component here.

```
export const getRecipes = () => {
  
    const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:10524`
    const RECIPES_URL =`${BASE_URL}/recipes`

    return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'START_FETCHING_RECIPES_REQUEST' });
      fetch(RECIPES_URL)
        .then(response =>{ return response.json()})
        .then(recipes => dispatch({ type: 'Get_Recipes', recipes }));
    };
    
  }
```

This is where I am trying to render the Recipe component from the get request

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
// import { getRecipes } from '../actions/getRecipes.js';
import Recipe from './Recipe.js'

class RecipeList extends Component {

// componentDidMount(){
//   getRecipes()
// }

render() {
   
   return (
    
  
    <div>
     {this.props.recipes.map(recipe => (<Recipe recipe={recipe} key={recipe.id} />))}
    </div>
   )
    
  }
}

export default RecipeList;
```

**Edit: Added reducer**

```
switch(action.type){
        case 'Add_Recipe':
            const recipe = {
                
                name: action.name,
                ingredients: action.ingredients,
                chef_name: action.chef_name,
                origin: action.origin,
                category: action.category
                
            }

            return{
                ...state,
                recipes: [...state.recipes, recipe],
            }
          
          case 'START_FETCHING_RECIPES_REQUEST':
            return {
                ...state,
            recipes: [...state.recipes],
            requesting: true
        }
        case 'Get_Recipes':
            return {
                ...state, recipes: action.recipes,
                requesting: false
            }
        

          default:
            return state
        
    }
}
```

How can I correct this to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual solution to this was I needed to have an explicit return in my mapStateToProp function.

Eg.

```
const mapStateToProp = state =>{
  return {
         recipes: state.recipes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

You are not passing the recipes to the `RecipeList` component that were fetched and presumably stored in state, and fed back to the UI via `RecipeContainer`.

## Solution

Pass the `recipe` state from `RecipeContainer` to `RecipeList` as a prop. and then render/map the recipes from `props`.

RecipeContainer

```
class RecipeContainer extends Component{
  componentDidMount() {
    getRecipes();
  }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <RecipeInput postRecipes={this.props.postRecipes} /> 
        <RecipeList getRecipes={this.props.recipes} /> // <-- pass recipe state
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  recipes: state.recipes,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    postRecipes: (recipe) => dispatch(postRecipes(recipe)),
    getRecipes: () => dispatch(getRecipes())
  }
};
```

RecipeList

```
class RecipeList extends Component { 
  render() {
    const { recipes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
       {recipes.map(recipe => (
         <Recipe recipe={recipe} key={recipe.id} />
       ))}
      </div>
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: What would my fetch request look like in this case. This seems logically, because before I saw this I was starting to do the samething

Comment: The reason I am asking is recipes in the RecipeList component comes back undefined.

Comment: @Stitch So are you saying that the `recipes` object/array in your redux state is undefined? Can you update your question to include your `getRecipes` action creator and reducer code?

Comment: I included my modified getRecipe to what I have for it now, and my reducer is at the bottom

Comment: @Stitch Where is the action creator for getting recipes? You should have a function somewhere that does the fetch and dispatches an action (perhaps `ADD_RECIPES`) that the reducer handles and stores in your state. `RecipeContainer` has a `getRecipes` action so I assumed that was it and that your redux state was working. My answer assumes that all works and you simply need to pass that updated state on to the component that renders the recipe list.

Comment: So I have a postRecipes action that post to the api and that works. My dispatch contains the type which in this case is ADD_RECIPE, and the payload as well. I have a my json file open with what I created earlier. Just trying to do a get request to the api to display content as you mentioned

Comment: @Stitch Are you just trying to make an asynchronous data fetch when the `RecipeList` component mounts to get the recipes from your backend and display it locally? I.E. skipping redux altogether? What does the `getRecipes` action do?

Comment: Correct, but for this project I am required to use redux. I even thought redux was over kill.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227465/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-stitch).