# Data is not flowing down to prop

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am having an issue getting data to flow down to my props to where when component rendered, the props are not displaying.

This is the container that contains my RecipeList Component
*---Note: I am getting my data asynchronously from a api btw *

```
import { postRecipes } from '../actions/postRecipes.js'
import { getRecipes } from '../actions/getRecipes'


class RecipesContainer extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getRecipes()
      }
    

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
               <RecipeInput postRecipes={this.props.postRecipes} /> 
               <RecipeList recipes={this.props.recipes} />
            </div>
        )
    }

    

}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        recipes: state.recipes
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return{
    postRecipes: (recipe) => dispatch(postRecipes(recipe)),
    getRecipes: () => dispatch(getRecipes())
    // deleteRecipe: id => dispatch({type: 'Delete_Recipe', id})
    }
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(RecipesContainer)
```

Here is my RecipeList component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Recipe from './Recipe.js'

class RecipeList extends Component {



render() {
   const { recipes } = this.props
   return (
    
      
    <div>
      
     {recipes.map((recipe,index) =>  <Recipe recipe={recipe} key={index} />)}
    </div>
   )
    
  }
}

export default RecipeList;
```

And here is the Recipe component that it mapping as I enter and submit a recipe

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'


class Recipe extends Component {
   
    render(){
        
        return(
            <div>
            <h3>Name: {this.props.name}</h3>
            <p>Category:{this.props.category}</p> <-------this one I will have to call differently since this is a one to many relationship
            <p>Chef Name: {this.props.chef_name}</p>
            <p>Origin: {this.props.origin}</p>
            <p>Ingredients: {this.props.ingredients}</p>
            </div>
             
        )
    }

}

export default Recipe
```

**EDIT**: Added getRecipe action as requested.

```
export const getRecipes = () => {
  
    const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:10524`
    const RECIPES_URL =`${BASE_URL}/recipes`

    return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'START_FETCHING_RECIPES_REQUEST' });
      fetch(RECIPES_URL)
        .then(response =>{ return response.json()})
        .then(recipes => { return console.log(recipes), dispatch({ type: 'Get_Recipes', recipes })});
       
        
    };

    
    
  }
```

Why isn't it displaying my results? I did console to make I was return my api data, and the Recipe component is rendering as just the html tags are rendering just fine.

Comment: In the future, "isn't displaying my results" and "having an issue" are not specific and make it confusing to understand. Try to be as specific as possible when asking questions about the issue.

Comment: What happened from [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65757574/props-not-displaying-from-fetch-call) when your code was working?

Comment: @DrewReese issue was in my mapStateToProp function. I update the code in the question. The mapStateToProp function need to have a explicit return, not a implicit return. The component is rendering, just not displaying. I console.log my the results from getRecipe function and its returning results from api

Comment: Is this issue here that the `Recipe` component is rendering nothing, or that `name`, `category`, etc... are not rendering? I think @AndyRay has the answer. You pass only a `recipe` prop, so in the component you need to access `this.props.recipe.name` etc...

Comment: That worked, I was doing that earlier, but I think that was prior to my recent push to git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass in a prop called `recipe` to your `<Recipe />` component, but your component reads from a non-existant `this.props.name`, etc.

Comment: Thank you btw. This helped out. I made some changes prior to this questions, and just didn't retrace my steps

Answer (score 0):

In your recipe list component, try this.

```
{recipes ? recipes.map((recipe,index) =>  <Recipe recipe={recipe} key={index} />) : null}
```